# Jquery, how to push in an array at a specific index?

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing

I can't figure out how to push a string in an array at a specific index.

Here is my array : `var list = ['',''];`

I would like to be able to replace, for example, the first array entry, so the list would be : 
`list = ['something',''];`

I tried to found a function for that, but nothing came up...

I know that I can add a string to an array using 
`list.push('something');` but I don't know how to do something like `list.pushThisAt(string, index);`

I need your help !

Comment: try something like `list[0] = "somthing"`

Comment: As simply as that and I didn't think about it ! Thank you !